# Ignore coverage HTML files from Vite + React HMR

Tags: vite, hot-module-replacement

I have a project set up using `vite` with the `@vitejs/plugin-react` extension. I'm using the basic config of

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react({ include: ['src'] })]
})
```

In the dev server output I'm seeing page reloads of my coverage HTML files, for example

```
8:09:45 PM [vite] page reload coverage/lcov-report/App.tsx.html
```

My coverage files are located in the project root with a directory of `coverage`. I've tried a number of settings in the Vite config, such as

```
optimizeDeps: {
  entries: ['index.html'],
  exclude: ['coverage']
}
```

and

```
server: {
  watch: {
    exclude: ['coverage']
  }
}
```

however neither of these seem to have any effect. I also tried the following on the React plugin itself

```
exclude: /coverage/
```

but no dice. I would expect that a path like `coverage` would be excluded by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```json
  server: {
    watch: {
      ignored: ['**/coverage/**'],
    },
  }
```

Comment: Either I'm blind, or this wasn't in the [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-watch) before. Thanks!

Comment: Or rather than `'**/coverage/**` you can do `path.resolve(__dirname, './coverage')` to ignore only the top level `coverage` folder

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a consequence of Storybook's internal Vite server being reconfigured on the fly and overriding the base configuration for Vite [described above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73543133/141881).

In addition to

```
server: {
  watch: {
    exclude: ['coverage']
  }
}
```

in `vite.config.ts` I *also* had to configure the following in `.storybook/main.ts`:

```js
import { InlineConfig, mergeConfig } from 'vite'

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  /* ... */
  viteFinal: (config: InlineConfig) => mergeConfig(config, {
    server: {
      watch: { ignored: ['**/coverage/**'] },
    },
  }),
  /* ... */
}
```